# REST Webservice in PHP MySQL JSON - Inserting empty values to database

Tags: php, mysql, json, rest

I am using `Advanced Rest Client` on Google Chrome for the `POST` requests.
Everything works and I even get the message `User has been successfully registered!` but on looking in to the database what I see is that, the values for `attributes` viz `firstname`, `lastname` etc are just BLANK though the query is issued successfully.
What is wrong ?

`create.php`

```
<?php

require_once 'connect.php';


if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
// Get post data`
    $firstName = isset($_POST['firstname']) ? mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['firstname']) : "";
    $lastName = isset($_POST['lastname']) ? mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['lastname']) : "";
    $email = isset($_POST['email']) ? mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['email']) : "";
    $password = isset($_POST['password']) ? sha1(md5(mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['password']))) : "";
    $status = 0; // Here we set by default status In-active.
    // Save data into database
    $query = "INSERT INTO users (firstname,lastname,email,password,status) VALUES ('{$firstName}',
    '{$lastName}','{$email}','{$password}','{$status}')";

    $insert = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

    if($insert){
        $data = array("result" => 1, "message" => "User has been successfully registered!");
        } else {
        $data = array("result" => 0, "message" => "Error!");
    }
}
else {
    $data = array("result" => 0, "message" => "Incorrect Request Method!");
}

mysqli_close($connection);
/* JSON Response */
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

[image: Screenshots From The REST Client]
[image: Screenshots From The REST Client]

[image: Screenshot From Database]

Comment: i dont know the "Advanced Rest Client", but it seems you are sending your data as headers. To get them via `$_POST` superglobal, you should send them as (form)data with your request

Comment: Yeah! I figured that out and fixed it. Even sending as form data inserts EMPTY values. I have updated the screenshots. Kindly have a look.

Comment: Put the resulting query in your output and check whether the query is correct or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your parameters into the request body, not the header. Perhaps this is done in the "Payload" section of your HTTP client? Also, do you need to `json_decode` the POST data in PHP since you are sending the data as JSON?

Try to debug by dumping out the blank values in the `$_POST` array.

Also, you may want to make your back-end more robust by validating the data that gets sent through. For instance, do not accept NULL values for every parameter you receive.

Comment: I have been trying the Payload now. Same results. EMPTY. I would have the backend robust when I find the skeleton working.,

Comment: Noticed you are sending the data in JSON format. Do you need to json_decode on the PHP side?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the problem had been in my `Advanced Rest Client`
I was sending the `payload` as `application/json` and it wasn't getting the POST data but on changing the `Content-Typ`e to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, things worked!

Comment: Yes. The other alternative would be to decode the JSON in PHP.